# ERROR : enum is not e member of the class

Tags: c++

I have declared an enum inside the class as in the below :

```
class Personne{

    public:
        enum class Genre { HOMME, FEMME, INDERTEMINE };
        Personne();
        Personne(const char*,const char*,Personne::Genre);
        const char *getPrenom() const;
        const char *getNom()const;
        Personne::Genre getGenre() const;


    private:
        const char * nom;
        const char * prenom;

};
```

While doing this test :

```
TEST_CASE("Personne1") {
    const char * prenom   = "Bruce";
    const char * nom      = "Wayne";
    Personne::Genre genre = Personne::HOMME;
    Personne p(prenom, nom, genre);

    REQUIRE( prenom    == p.getPrenom());
    REQUIRE( nom       == p.getNom());
    REQUIRE( genre     == p.getGenre());
}
```

It gives me an error : 'HOMME' is not a member of 'Personne'.
Personne::Genre genre = Personne::HOMME;

Can you fix that please it's very important?

Comment: `Personne::Genre::HOMME`, since you declared `Genre` as an `enum class`, you need to fully qualify it.

Comment: I shoud not change the test

Comment: Remove `class` after `enum`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to write

```
Personne::Genre genre = Personne::Genre::HOMME;
```

because Genre is a scoped enumeration.

Or you could declare an unscoped enumeration in the class.

```
enum Genre { HOMME, FEMME, INDERTEMINE };
```

Comment: I should not change the test, I should adapt the test with the code

Comment: @AliceLangertton • the test is broken.  You should change the test.  Tests test the code.  The code should not conform to the test, that's backwards.

Comment: @Eljay Good advice, unless the tests are coming from an external source (like the teacher for example).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen • Agreed, in that case it is best to optimize the situation for the best grade, rather than to optimize for being correct.

Comment: @Eljay "in that case it is best to optimize the situation for the best grade, rather than to optimize for being correct" - No. It is better to be correct and then educate the teacher about his/her broken tests. Ignore irrelevant fluff like "grades".

Comment: @JesperJuhl • depending on the teacher, that may adversely impact the grade, or may enhance the grade.  A bit of a gambit.  Know thy teacher before going down that path.  (I actually agree with you that grades are fluff.  But for many people, they are important.)

Comment: @Eljay in the end, grades don't matter one bit. Being able to do your job or not does. Don't optimize for irrelevant metrics.